# Decimal vs Double math accuracy

Tags: .net, vb.net

I noticed that math operations are sometimes less accurate for Decimals than they are for Doubles. For example, when I run this code:

```
    Dim a As Decimal = 1
    Dim b As Decimal = 3
    Dim c As Decimal = (a / b) * b

    Dim x As Double = 1
    Dim y As Double = 3
    Dim z As Double = (x / y) * y

    Console.WriteLine(c)
    Console.WriteLine(a = c)
    Console.WriteLine(z)
    Console.WriteLine(x = z)
```

It outputs:

```
0.9999999999999999999999999999
False
1
True
```

As you can see, the Decimals give the floating point issue (0.999999) and the Doubles give the exact number (1).

If Decimals are supposed to be more accurate than Doubles, why did this happen?

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330988/double-vs-decimal-rounding-in-c-sharp/15331162#15331162

Comment: The short version is it's not really true that "decimals are more accurate than doubles".  If you're dealing with dollars and cents, then sure, a decimal is the way to go, because they can store the exact value 1/100.  But neither a decimal nor a double can store 1/3 exactly.  So there's some truncation or rounding, which happens to give the exact answer for 1/3 * 3 in the case of the double, but not for the decimal.  I give much more detail on this in my previous answer linked above.